# missing resources/build errors after shutting down and restarting eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget, eclipse-adt

I seem to have developed an odd problem that I can't find a solutiuon for.

I finished working on my app and closed the emulator and eclipse as I normally do.  They next day I started up eclipse and ran my app and it crashed with an inflation error when I tried to access my options menu.

```
02-09 06:21:31.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15229): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView
```

Then I discovered it crashes when it tried to inflate a context menu.  (The select_dialog.xml file *is* in it's proper place in the SDK).

```
02-09 06:22:49.207: E/AndroidRuntime(15239): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/select_dialog.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x109005e
```

Options menu code:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    int tab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
    if (tab == 0) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Test1");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Test2");
    } else if (tab == 1) {
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Test3");
        menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Test4");
    } else if (tab == 2) {
        menu.add(0, 4, 0, "Enter WPC");
        menu.add(0, 5, 0, "Clear All WPCs");
    } else if (tab == 3) {
        menu.add(0, 6, 0, "Edit Notes");
        menu.add(0, 7, 0, "Clear Notes");
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Context menu code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.list1: {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Tool CC Menu");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit/Add Cutter Comp Info");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Clear Cutter Comp Info");
        break;
    }
    case R.id.list2: {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("WPC Menu");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit/Add WPC Info");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Clear WPC Info");
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Both of these bits of menu code worked fine last night... I tried cleaning the project, then I thought perhaps my SDK got corrupted, so I tried checking the disk and it came up fine, so then I re-installed the SDK and I still have the problem.

I'm at a loss as to what to look at or try next.  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those following this, I found the issue.  It would appear that something got corrupted in the emulator.

I deleted the AVD I was using, recreated it and now everything is working like it should again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should to find the file in your project.
Then, Locate at line 17 to check what's the wrong.

Comment: Umm, read the error... it's a binary file supplied with the SDK.  No finding line 17 toi check it.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that your R.java file is corrupted.
This is a generated file, that you can find it in gen folder.
First, you can try to delete it. It will regenerate when you run the project.
Or what i would recommend, is to make a new project and copy paste your old classes and xml's in this new project. For sure it will work.

Comment: Tried both, and I still have the same problem.  This is really frustrating.  Thanks for the attempt to help.

Comment: can you tell me what your logcat says?

Comment: this is a very simple code...what you wrote here...i suggest to write it again...try to start from here...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html